# How can I create a Yesod form where I can select from a dropdown list where the list is passed as an argument?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I would like to create a form in which I pass a `[a]` an an argument and get back an `MForm Handler (FormResult a, Widget)`.

I have attempted to implement this using functions such as `selectFieldList` but have not been able to find a solution. I have not been able to find an answer anywhere on google. I have found many examples where dropdown lists have been used as individual fields in a larger form but none where the dropdown list is the entire form itself.

Edit:

I have managed to make a form that compiles. Unfortunately I am unable to tell if it works the way I would like because I cannot get it to render.

Here are the key functions I am working with (they all compile):

```
mkCityStringM :: [PG.DbCity] -> [(T.Text, PG.DbCity)]
mkCityStringM xs = zip (map (T.pack . showDbCity) xs) xs

data ContainCity =
  ContainCity
    { getCity :: PG.DbCity
    }
  deriving (Show)

ambiguityForm :: [PG.DbCity] -> AForm Handler ContainCity
ambiguityForm cities = ContainCity 
   <$> areq (selectFieldList cityMap) "City" Nothing
  where
    cityMap :: [(T.Text, PG.DbCity)]
    cityMap = W.mkCityStringM cities
```

The problem is when I try to actually use this table I run into issues. Here is code that works just fine for me:

```
locationForm :: Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult BasicLocation, Widget)
locationForm = renderDivs $ BasicLocation
  <$> areq textField "City:" Nothing
  <*> areq textField "Country:" (Just "United States")

postAmbiguityR :: [PG.DbCity] -> Handler Html
postAmbiguityR cs = do 
  (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost locationForm
  defaultLayout $ do 
  [whamlet|
    <p>who cares
  |]
```

On the other hand I have this code:

```
postAmbiguityR :: [PG.DbCity] -> Handler Html
postAmbiguityR cs = do 
  (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost (ambiguityForm cs) --only difference
  defaultLayout $ do 
  [whamlet|
    <p> WHATEVER
  |]
```

which throws me this error:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘blaze-markup-0.8.2.5:Text.Blaze.Internal.Markup
                                    -> MForm (HandlerFor Base) (FormResult a0, xml0)’
                  with actual type ‘AForm Handler ContainCity’
    • Possible cause: ‘ambiguityForm’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the first argument of ‘generateFormPost’, namely
        ‘(ambiguityForm cs)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost (ambiguityForm cs)
      In the expression:
        do (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost (ambiguityForm cs)
           defaultLayout
             $ do (do (asWidgetT . toWidget)
                        ((blaze-markup-0.8.2.5:Text.Blaze.Internal.preEscapedText . T.pack)
                           "<html><header></header>
<form method="post" action="")
                      ....)
    |
132 |   (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost (ambiguityForm cs)
    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This error message does not make sense to me. It says a possible cause is that `ambiguity form is applied to too many arguments` but does not seem to be the case as the form takes a list of PG.DbCity's and that is exactly what I supplied it.

Comment: Can you explain why a form consisting of a single `selectFieldList` field doesn't work for you?  Is the problem that there's a field label and/or submit button?  Do you have an example of an `MForm` that comes close but has some specific problem that you want to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ambiguityForm` is an `AForm`, but `generateFormPost` expects an `MForm`.  To convert it to an `MForm` suitable for rendering, you need to use `renderDivs`, like you did in your `locationForm` example.  You can **either** do this in the definition of `ambiguityForm`, which will change its type/defintion to look something like:

```
ambiguityForm :: [PG.DbCity] -> Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult ContainCity, Widget)
ambiguityForm cities = renderDivs $ ContainCity ...
```

**or** you can leave `ambiguityForm` unchanged and add `renderDivs` at the usage site:

```
postAmbiguityR :: [PG.DbCity] -> Handler Html
postAmbiguityR cs = do 
  (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost (renderDivs (ambiguityForm cs))
  defaultLayout $ do 
  [whamlet|
    <p> WHATEVER
  |]
```